# Why are Eclipse project folders marked Derived still showing up in the Synchronization view?

Tags: eclipse, cvs, directory, synchronization, derived

How can I get the Sync view to ignore my Derived folders in Eclipse?

---

In the past, I recall that marking my Ant build output folders as Derived (right-click on folder, select properties, check the Derived checkbox) would:

- keep them from showing up in the Open Resource dialog
- correctly ignore them as not being legitimate outgoing changes in my CVS Sync view

When I mark the Ant build folder as Derived now, the contents are still showing up in my Sync view as outgoing changes.

What am I doing wrong?  Has something changed with Eclipse?

I have tried cleaning, rebuilding, opening and closing the project, re-importing the project, and launching Eclipse with the -clean option.

Eclipse Version: 3.6.2, Build id: M20110210-1200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse has changes on this indeed. Now you have to either use Preferences/Team/Ignore Resources or add files/path to exclude from version control into local .cvsignore or per-repository CVSROOT/cvsignore

Cheers,
Max

Comment: They shouldn't show up in the Open Resources dialog, but CVS can only ignore resources specified in the .cvsignore file that also aren't on the server at all.